# The method put(Character, Integer) in the type HashMap<Character,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (char, int)

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting this error and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
char a[]=str.toCharArray();
    HashMap <Character,Integer> hm=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(hm.containsKey(a[i])){
            hm.put(a[i], hm.get(a[i])+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. However, the condition `hm.containsKey(a[i])` will never be `true` as the `HashMap` `hm` is empty when the `for` loop is executed, so I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: My login is not complete. In the else part I do something like hm.put(a[i], 1);

Comment: @d.j.brown I did what you suggested. I still get the same error.

Comment: it looks like a warning an IDE would give. I can compile your code fine using jdk_1.8.0_131 as long as I define `str` as a `String`, e.g. `String str = "abc";`.

Comment: Thats exactly how I have my str defined as well. Do you think reinstalling eclipse would work?

Comment: Question, do you have any classes called `Character` or `Integer` that may be being used over `java.lang.Character` and `java.lang.Integer`? If not then I'd consider at least closing and reopening the project in Eclipse / rebooting the machine. Try removing any settings/profiles if that does not work. Otherwise a reinstall may help(?)

Answer (score 0):

you can use
 `hm.put(a[i], hm.getOrDefault(a[i], 0) + 1);`

Answer (score -1):

The code complies and executes correctly (I've just added an initialization for missing characters  `hm.put(a[i], 1);`).

```
char a[]=str.toCharArray();
HashMap<Character,Integer> hm=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(hm.containsKey(a[i])){
        hm.put(a[i], hm.get(a[i])+1);
    }else{
        hm.put(a[i], 1);
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking the compiler is right because `char` is not `Character` and `int` is not `Integer`, but autoboxing should take care of this.

So we are missing some context.

The only way I could reproduce the same error was adding a mock Character class in the test class like this:

```
public class OneTest {

    private class Character{
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String str = "AABcDD";
        char a[]=str.toCharArray();
        HashMap<Character,Integer> hm=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(hm.containsKey(a[i])){
                hm.put(a[i], hm.get(a[i])+1);
            }else{
                hm.put(a[i], 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hm);
    }

}
```